# Can I run flexunit tests in the Flash Player instead of the browser?

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

I'm using Flash Builder 4 (beta 2) and FlexUnit 4, and instead of running my test suite in my browser I'd like to run my tests in the Flash Player.  I know that it's possible to execute tests in there -- Library projects already run in the Flash Player -- but application projects still insist on running tests in my default browser, which sits on another virtual desktop and necessitates a lot of screen switching.

Is this possible?